# Sorting structure elements in C and having them printed out

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, structure

I want to sort the `k_p` in descending order from largest to smallest and the `s_s_s` for the 10 students in the same way and print it out but I dont know how to do it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    float k_p;
    char i_p[30];
    int s_s_s;
};

int main() {
    struct student S[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("Student broj %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Koeficijent place: \t"); scanf("%d", &S[i].k_p);
        printf("Ime i prezime: \t"); scanf("%s", &S[i].i_p);
        printf("Stupanj strucne spreme: \t"); scanf("%f",&S[i].s_s_s);
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried with something like this but I don't know how to fit it into the code

```
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {     //Loop for comparing other values
        if (a[j] < a[i]) {            //Comparing other array elements
            int tmp = a[i];           //Using temporary variable for storing last value
            a[i] = a[j];              //replacing value
            a[j] = tmp;               //storing last value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting different sorted results? Becuase it cannot be guarenteed that k_p and s_s_s will always be in order for each struct. I would create a sort function that specifies which field to sort by. For comparing strings, use strcmp.

Comment: Are you asking to sort descending by `k_p` and if two values of `k_p` are equal, then by `s_s_s`? Otherwise, sorting by `k_p` and then sorting again be `s_s_s` would just result in a sort by `s_s_s`. Or, are you saying you want the capability of sorting by either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the entire structure, you need to use a proper swapping function which will swap two structure elements rather than two integers.

Since this structure contains an integer, a character array and a float, the swapping function should take care to swap all three elements.

```
/* in Global area */ 
float ftemp;
char chartemp[30];
int itemp;

void swap(struct student *a, struct student *b)
{

    /* swap the float */
    ftemp  = a->k_p;
    a->k_p = b->b_p;
    b->k_p = ftemp;

    /* swap the array */
    strcpy(chartemp, a->i_p);
    strcpy(a->i_p, b->i_p);
    strcpy(b->i_p, chartemp);

    /* swap the int */
    itemp    = a->s_s_s;
    a->s_s_s = b-> s_s_s;
    b->s_s_s = itemp;

}
```

You can then use any sorting algorithm to sort, e.g. bubble sort, insertion sort, merge sort calling the function above to swap the values.

Note - The temporary variables are put in the global area as the swap function will be called many times and this will give a small boost in run time. If you have many elements that you wish to sort in this manner(more than 100000), a structure is not the ideal way to go about it. Better for this is a linked list. In a linked list, you will only need to swap pointers and not the entire data.

Answer (score 0):

One approach: create an **array of ints** that is the *same size* as your array of structs (array S), and is *initialized from 0 to n-1* (where n is the size).

Sort this array of ints with any sorting algorithm you see fit, and treat each integer from array A as an **index** of your array S.

By sorting the array of indices according to either k_p or s_s_s, you can effectively print your array S as if it was sorted by descending k_p or s_s_s.

Let's use bubble sort (a simple sorting algorithm to illustrate) and we will sort according to descending k_p values:

```
    int A[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    float k1,k2;
    // bubble sort for descending order
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {   
        k1 = &S[i].k_p;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)             
        {
            k2 = &S[j].k_p;
            if (k1 < k2)               
            {
                // remember you're only switching the ints in array A
                int tmp = A[i];         
                A[i] = A[j];           
                A[j] = tmp;             
            }
        }
    }
```

** Disclaimer: I didn't test the code but this is the general idea.

Comment: Better, simply create an array of pointers [10] to `struct student` and initialize the array to `S` and then sort the pointers by either `k_p` or `s_s_s` which would leave the original unchanged. (a second array of pointers could then be sorted by the other member)